# EF during codefirst fails in localdb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I got the next error in my InnerException `{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}` 
When i publish to Azure everything works, but on localhost it crashes.

ConnectionString

`<add name="AccountingDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AccountingDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

On web writes the next error

`Cannot attach the file 'D:\AccountingWebApplication\AccountingWebApplication\App_Data\AccountingWebApplication.Db.AccountingContext.mdf' as database 'AccountingWebApplication.Db.AccountingContext'.`

Answer (score 0):

Is your config file set up to use localdb?

```
<entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory 
  type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
        EntityFramework">
<parameters>
  <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```